# Server side for dojo-based+Qt5 application

Tags: javascript, ajax, dojo, webserver, qt5

I'm studing dojo to create web applications. 
The HTTP server will be a Windows machine with IIS.

On the same machine will run my own Qt5 application to provide all backend logic for the web pages. I'm going to use dojo for them.

I wonder what is the best way to exchange data (JSON) between the client (dojo) and my application (Qt5).

In the docs I've learned how to use the AJAX methods to make HTTP requests (https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.10/ajax/index.html). But they rely on the HTTP server, instead I need to communicate with my Qt5 application.

What do you recommend? 
Of course I'm trying to avoid (web)sockets!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Dojo main modules for loading data in your application are based on AJAX, examples `require`, `dojo.xhrGet`, the content is actually in JSON format. Dojo has also support for restful service with module as `dojo/store/JsonRest`.

Dojo also offer you some [support for socket using dojox](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.10/dojox/socket.)

It really depends of the scope of your Qt5 application if you need bidirectional communication web sockets could be a reasonable solution.